# Unable to find double quotes to close a string

Tags: java, html, string, jsp

"String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote"

I'm having problems with finding the problem stated above. I've searched high and low through my code, and I'm still unable to indentify the error. It says that the error is found at line 12.

Here's my code:
http://pastebin.com/WgD3ApR0

I'm coding in `JSP`.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
  <%@ page import="java.util.*"%>

  <%
  response.addHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");
  response.addHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
  response.addHeader("Expires","0");

  // Login variables //    
  String username = request.getParameter("username");
  String password = request.getParameter("password");

 // SQL login variables //

 // Role variables //

 // Encryption of session ID //
    String sessId = "" + (new java.util.Random()).nextInt(1000);    

    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    String conURL= "jdbc:odbc:HOD_DATA";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(conURL);
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    String query = "select user_group from login
                    where username = '"+username+"'
                    and password = '"+password+"'
                    ";   

    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
    Boolean result = rs.next();

    // Might have to pass the login details over to the other pages //

    if(result == true){

    // Ashton //
    if(rs.getString("user_group").equals("admin")){
    String url = response.encodeURL("Test.jsp?sessId=" + sessId);
    response.sendRedirect(url);
    }

    // Joseph //
    else if(rs.getString("user_group").equals("clerk")){
    String url = response.encodeURL("ClerkPage.jsp?sessId=" + sessId);
    response.sendRedirect(url);
    }

    // Gaurav //
    else if(rs.getString("user_group").equals("customer")){
    String url = response.encodeURL("HomePage.jsp?sessId=" + sessId);
    response.sendRedirect(url);
    }

    // Jiong xu //
    else if(rs.getString("user_group").equals("sales")){
    String url = response.encodeURL("SalesPage.jsp?sessId=" + sessId);
    response.sendRedirect(url);
    }

    // Wen jie //
    else if(rs.getString("user_group").equals("operations")){
    String url = response.encodeURL("OperationsPage.jsp?sessId=" + sessId);
    response.sendRedirect(url);
    }       
    }

    else {
    response.sendRedirect("LoginPage.jsp"); // If the above fails, redirect to login // 
    }

    rs.close();
    st.close();
    con.close();

  %>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you believe in `SQL Injection`?

Answer (score 3):

It's most likely this part:

```
String query = "select user_group from login
                                    where username = '"+username+"'
                                    and password = '"+password+"'
                                    ";
```

Line breaks are not allowed in the middle of a string in Java.

Answer (score 2):

first Your way for running the query is kinda too old and too dangerous, it's better to use `prepared statements` here, like this

```
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("select user_group from login where username=? and password=?");
st.setString(1,username);
st.setString(2,password);
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
```

Second if you are using for example `postgresql` database, it's better to use its own implicit driver rather than its `ODBC` driver for better performance.

Comment: I believe my school is still teaching us the old syllabus. Thanks for highlighting to me the more modern approach of doings thing :) I'll keep that in mind